# AMPscript LookUpRows error

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm having an issue when I try to load dynamically content into an email using LookupRows function from AMPscript in ExactTarget (Salesforce). Maybe you can help. Appreciate it.

I have a LookupRows data extension where I have a list of ContentAreaIDs which I try to load into my email HTML using %%=ContentArea(@ContentAreaXX)=%% (XX = a number from 1-13, I have 13 content areas to load into email).

This is what I did step by step:
1. setting up 13 content areas with the content to be pulled in (HTML type content areas)
2. copying the ContentAreaID from each of those 13 and adding to the LookupRows data extension
3. calling the content areas in my HTML code like this %%=ContentArea(@ContentAreaXX)=%%

When I try to preview in ET I receive this error:
Unable to generate preview
A scripting error has occurred.
Invalid value specified for function parameter.
Function Name: ContentArea
Parameter Name: ContentID
Parameter Ordinal: 1
Parameter Type: Numeric
Submitted Value:

These are the data extensions used (one for send, another for the LookupRows):
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3G2k1oFH3OUa041eGJ1RXZPZ2c&usp=sharing

Can you point me to what I'm doing wrong?

This is the HTML:

```
%%[
Var @card_type, @Row, @rows, @ac, @au, @ea, @se, @ContentArea1, @ContentArea2, @ContentArea3, @ContentArea4, @ContentArea5, @ContentArea6, @ContentArea7, @ContentArea8, @ContentArea9, @ContentArea10, @ContentArea11, @ContentArea12, @ContentArea13

SET @card_type = [CARD_TYPE]
SET @ac = [AC]
SET @au = [AU]
SET @ea = [EA]
SET @se = [SE]

IF Not Empty(@card_type) THEN
SET @rows = LookupRows("forum-lookup-rows - 1","card_type", [CARD_TYPE])
ENDIF

IF RowCount(@rows) > 0 THEN
SET @rows = Row(@rows,1)
SET @ContentArea1 = Field(@rows,"ContentArea1")
SET @ContentArea2 = Field(@rows,"ContentArea2")
SET @ContentArea3 = Field(@rows,"ContentArea3")
SET @ContentArea4 = Field(@rows,"ContentArea4")
SET @ContentArea5 = Field(@rows,"ContentArea5")
SET @ContentArea6 = Field(@rows,"ContentArea6")
SET @ContentArea11 = Field(@rows,"ContentArea11")

IF @ac == 'n' THEN
SET @ContentArea7 = Field(@row,"ContentArea7")
ELSEIF @ea == 'n' THEN
SET @ContentArea8 = Field(@row,"ContentArea8")
ELSEIF @au == 'n' THEN
SET @ContentArea9 = Field(@row,"ContentArea9")
SET @ContentArea12 = Field(@row,"ContentArea12")
/*ELSEIF @au == 'y' THEN
SET @ContentArea13 = Field(@row,"ContentArea13")*/
ELSEIF @se == 'n' THEN
SET @ContentArea10 = Field(@row,"ContentArea10")
ENDIF
ENDIF

]%%

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charSET=utf-8" />
      <meta content="initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
      <title></title>
      <style type="text/css">
         #outlook a {padding:0;}
         body{width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}
         .ExternalClass {width:100%;}
         .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;}
         img {outline:none; text-decoration:none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;}
         a img {border:none;}
         @media only screen and (max-width: 629px) {
         body[yahoo] .hide {display:none !important;}
         body[yahoo] table {width:100% !important; background:#ffffff !important;}
         body[yahoo] img[class="fluid"] {max-width:100% !important;width:100% !important;height: auto !important;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic !important;}
         body[yahoo] table[class="grey"] {background-color:#f9fafa !important;}
         body[yahoo] table[class="noBorder"] {border:0 !important;}
         body[yahoo] table[class="social"] {width:210px !important;}
         body[yahoo] table[class="centered"] img, body[yahoo] table[class="grey"] img{margin:0 auto !important; text-align:center}
         body[yahoo] a[class="footerLink"] {display:block !important; padding:10px !important;}
         body[yahoo] .title {font-size:15px !important;}
         body[yahoo] img[class="card"] {width:53px !important; height:34px !important;}
         body[yahoo] table[class="green"] {background-color:#19b24b !important;}
         body[yahoo] table[class="borderBottom"] {border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc !important; margin-bottom:20px !important}
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body yahoo="fix">
      <table style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" width="630" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
         <tr>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; color:#666666;  margin:0;" align="center">
                 %%=ContentArea(@ContentArea1)=%%  
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; color:#666666;  margin:0;" align="center">
                 %%=ContentArea(@ContentArea2)=%%  
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; color:#666666;  margin:0;" align="center">
                 %%=ContentArea(@ContentArea3)=%%  
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; color:#666666;  margin:0;" align="center">
                 %%=ContentArea(@ContentArea4)=%%  
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; color:#666666;  margin:0;" align="center">
                 %%=ContentArea(@ContentArea5)=%%  
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; color:#666666;  margin:0;" align="center">
                 %%=ContentArea(@ContentArea6)=%%  
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; color:#666666;  margin:0;" align="center">
                 %%=ContentArea(@ContentArea7)=%%  
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; color:#666666;  margin:0;" align="center">
                 %%=ContentArea(@ContentArea8)=%%  
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; color:#666666;  margin:0;" align="center">
                 %%=ContentArea(@ContentArea9)=%%  
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; color:#666666;  margin:0;" align="center">
                 %%=ContentArea(@ContentArea10)=%%  
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; color:#666666;  margin:0;" align="center">
                 %%=ContentArea(@ContentArea11)=%%  
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; color:#666666;  margin:0;" align="center">
                 %%=ContentArea(@ContentArea12)=%%  
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; color:#666666;  margin:0;" align="center">
                 %%=ContentArea(@ContentArea13)=%%  
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
<custom name="opencounter" type="tracking">
```

Comment: I'd temporarily remove  the ContentArea() functions in the body of your email and output all of the @ContentArea variable values right after your AMPScript block.  Can you do a Send preview on that and post the results?

Comment: Thanks Adam, I did as you said. I output the (@)ContentArea1, 2, until 13 values into the body area and I see all ContentAreaIDs except the ones that are supposed to be output from the second AMPscript block starting with IF (@)ac == 'n' THEN. I removed that second block and I called only content areas 1-6 but I receive the error again, it should resolve something like %%=ContentArea("12345")=%% for each of those 7 therefore I should see the dynamic copy bu is not doing it, same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd move the retrieval inside your `@card_type` conditional and output each `@contentArea` value.  Like this:

```
%%[
Var @card_type, @Row, @rows, @ac, @au, @ea, @se, @ContentArea1, @ContentArea2, @ContentArea3, @ContentArea4, @ContentArea5, @ContentArea6, @ContentArea7, @ContentArea8, @ContentArea9, @ContentArea10, @ContentArea11, @ContentArea12, @ContentArea13

SET @card_type = [CARD_TYPE]
SET @ac = [AC]
SET @au = [AU]
SET @ea = [EA]
SET @se = [SE]

IF Not Empty(@card_type) THEN

    SET @rows = LookupRows("forum-lookup-rows - 1","card_type", [CARD_TYPE])

    IF RowCount(@rows) > 0 THEN

        SET @row = Row(@rows,1)
        SET @ContentArea1 = Field(@row,"ContentArea1")
        SET @ContentArea2 = Field(@row,"ContentArea2")
        SET @ContentArea3 = Field(@row,"ContentArea3")
        SET @ContentArea4 = Field(@row,"ContentArea4")
        SET @ContentArea5 = Field(@row,"ContentArea5")
        SET @ContentArea6 = Field(@row,"ContentArea6")
        SET @ContentArea11 = Field(@row,"ContentArea11")

        IF @ac == 'n' THEN
            SET @ContentArea7 = Field(@row,"ContentArea7")
        ELSEIF @ea == 'n' THEN
            SET @ContentArea8 = Field(@row,"ContentArea8")
        ELSEIF @au == 'n' THEN
            SET @ContentArea9 = Field(@row,"ContentArea9")
            SET @ContentArea12 = Field(@row,"ContentArea12")
        /*ELSEIF @au == 'y' THEN
        SET @ContentArea13 = Field(@row,"ContentArea13")*/
        ELSEIF @se == 'n' THEN
            SET @ContentArea10 = Field(@row,"ContentArea10")
        ENDIF
    ENDIF

ENDIF

]%%

@card_type: %%=v(@card_type)=%%<br>
@ac: %%=v(@ac)=%%<br>
@au: %%=v(@au)=%%<br>
@ea: %%=v(@ea)=%%<br>
@se: %%=v(@se)=%%<br><br>
@ContentArea1: %%=v(@ContentArea1)=%%<br>
@ContentArea2: %%=v(@ContentArea2)=%%<br>
@ContentArea3: %%=v(@ContentArea3)=%%<br>
@ContentArea4: %%=v(@ContentArea4)=%%<br>
@ContentArea5: %%=v(@ContentArea5)=%%<br>
@ContentArea6: %%=v(@ContentArea6)=%%<br>
@ContentArea11: %%=v(@ContentArea11)=%%<br><br>
@ContentArea7: %%=v(@ContentArea7)=%%<br>
@ContentArea8: %%=v(@ContentArea8)=%%<br>
@ContentArea9: %%=v(@ContentArea9)=%%<br>
@ContentArea12: %%=v(@ContentArea12)=%%<br>
@ContentArea10: %%=v(@ContentArea10)=%%<br>
```

For any `@ContentArea*` field that's empty the email's going to blow up.  You'll either need to have some default content for those or conditionally display alternate content in the body of the email.  You might utilize an `iif()` function -- like this:

```
%%=iif(empty(@ContentArea1),"not found", ContentArea(@ContentArea1))=%%
```

Comment: Hi Adam, this is what I tried to say, I output the values for each of the ContentArea* like this %%[Output (v(@ContentArea1))]%% It output all ContentArea* values except the ones generated in the block of code starting with IF @ac == 'n' THEN. It didn't out the values for area 7, 8, 9, 10, 12 so my guessing is that the issue is with that code starting with IF (@)ac == 'n' THEN. Any ideas what could be wrong? Thanks mate, appreciate your help :)

Comment: Oh, i see the issue.  You're overwriting `@rows` in your example.  Should be `@row`.  I updated my example.

Comment: same error Adam, any other thoughts? :)

Comment: You got the same error on my code sample or yours?

Comment: I copied your AMPscript code. This is the error again:<br>Unable to generate preview<br>
A scripting error has occurred.<br>
Invalid value specified for function parameter.<br>
Function Name: ContentArea<br>
Parameter Name: ContentID<br>
Parameter Ordinal: 1<br>
Parameter Type: Numeric<br>
Submitted Value: <br>

Comment: I tried again and now it pulls all good but without the values for 7, 8, 9, 10, 12 (again). It's something with that this code that doesn't work: `code`IF @ac == 'n' THEN
            SET @ContentArea7 = Field(@row,"ContentArea7")
        ELSEIF @ea == 'n' THEN
            SET @ContentArea8 = Field(@row,"ContentArea8")
        ELSEIF @au == 'n' THEN
            SET @ContentArea9 = Field(@row,"ContentArea9")
            SET @ContentArea12 = Field(@row,"ContentArea12")
        
        ELSEIF @se == 'n' THEN
            SET @ContentArea10 = Field(@row,"ContentArea10")
        ENDIF`code`

Comment: Are you're sure it's not a data issue?

Comment: you were right Adam, it was a data thing after all. I went through the whole list of test subscribers and then I noticed for some of them it pulled dynamic content which made me think that the issue is whether or not the field is empty. So indeed when the field was empty the Content Area function was pulling in nothing instead of a Content Area ID. I added IF EMPTY / NOT EMPTY to the logic and now works. Thanks again for your help and suggestions :) Vic